# How to define classes in JavaScript that don't require a specific order when using JSContext of JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, swift, class, inheritance, javascriptcore

I am developing an iOS application where some parts need to be written in javascript.  JavaScript is an interpreted language so if we need to update the javascript files, we wouldn't need to send out a new iOS build, we would just need to download the latest version of the javascript file.  However, I am having issues with Subclassing.

I have the 3 classes in separate .js files. I am using JSContext from the JavaScriptCore framework (available to cocoa). So I load the JSContext using evaluateScript(_:).  It seems like I need to load each javascript file in the correct order, however, this doesn't seems scaleable as more and more classes are added it will be difficult to maintain the right order.

In an object oriented language like Swift, I can declare the classes and their subclasses in any order. JavaScript es6 seems to support subclassing as well, but it breaks if I don't define them in the right order.  I have 3 classes, Abe, Bob, and Cal.  Cal inherits from Bob and Bob inherits from Abe.

```
// Abe.js
class Abe {
    method() {
        return "Abe"
    }
}
// Bob.js
class Bob extends Abe {
  method() {
    return "Bob"
  }
}
// Cal.js
class Cal extends Bob {
  method() {
    return "Cal"
  }
}
```

Firstly I need to create a JSContext and then load the contents of each file.  My first example shows how I can load them in order.

```
let context = JSContext()!
context.evaluateScript(try! String(contentsOf: "path/to/Abe.js"))
context.evaluateScript(try! String(contentsOf: "path/to/Bob.js"))
context.evaluateScript(try! String(contentsOf: "path/to/Cal.js"))

context.evaluateScript("(new Abe()).method()") // <- returns "Abe"
context.evaluateScript("(new Bob()).method()") // <- returns "Bob"
context.evaluateScript("(new Cal()).method()") // <- returns "Cal"
```

It works as expected, however, if I accidentally mess up the ordering, I get an error.  Suppose I loaded Cal.js before Bob.js:

```
let context = JSContext()!
context.evaluateScript(try! String(contentsOf: "path/to/Abe.js"))
context.evaluateScript(try! String(contentsOf: "path/to/Cal.js"))
context.evaluateScript(try! String(contentsOf: "path/to/Bob.js"))

context.evaluateScript("(new Abe()).method()") // <- returns "Abe"
context.evaluateScript("(new Bob()).method()") // <- returns "Bob"
context.evaluateScript("(new Cal()).method()") // <- returns "undefined"
```

Since Cal inherits from Bob and Bob doesn't get loaded until later, Cal becomes undefined.

The simple fix is to maintain the exact order.  There are only three files so it is easy to eye-ball it and get the order right, but if there were hundreds of files it will be difficult to get the load order exactly right.

JSContext has evaluateScript(_:withSourceURL:) but it doesn't seem to work at all.  I expected to at least be able to instantiate Abe and call its method.:

```
let context = JSContext()!
context.evaluateScript("", withSourceURL: "path/to/Abe.js"))
context.evaluateScript("", withSourceURL: "path/to/Cal.js"))
context.evaluateScript("", withSourceURL: "path/to/Bob.js"))

context.evaluateScript("(new Abe()).method()") // <- returns "undefined"
context.evaluateScript("(new Bob()).method()") // <- returns "undefined"
context.evaluateScript("(new Cal()).method()") // <- returns "undefined"
```

Abe.js, Cal.js, and Bob.js are all local files. "path/to/Abe.js" is a URL to the file path; I omitted the url part for brevity.

Comment: `Bob` is not defined at `class Cal extends Bob` as logged at `console` `Uncaught ReferenceError: Bob is not defined`

Comment: Yes, I know that.  Look at my first code snippet where I define the classes in the correct order.  I purposely put "Cal"'s definition before "Bob"'s definition because I am looking for other workarounds.  The C language gets around the issue by using a header file.  How would we get around the same issue in JavaScript?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have the 3 classes in separate .js files.   I am trying to use JSContext from the JavaScriptCore framework (available to cocoa).  So I load the JSContext using evaluateScript() but it requires me to load classes in order (Abe, Bob, Cal).  But as the code base grows it will be harder and harder to keep files in the right order.

Comment: Have you considered including description of requirement at text of Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've revised the question to better describe my constraints.  I hope it's written as a better question...

Answer (score 0):

You are right about hoisting. In JavaScript, like functions, classes are hoisted, but they are not initialized until evaluation. So, in order for your code to work, you need to define the classes in the correct order. One solution though, is to define each class in a separate .js file, so you can `import` when you need to use it. For example:

```
// abe.js
export default class Abe {
  method() {
    return "Abe"
  }
}
```

---

```
// cal.js
import Bob from './bob'

export default class Cal extends Bob {
  method() {
    return "Cal"
  }
}
```

---

```
// bob.js
import Abe from './abe'

export default class Bob extends Abe {
  method() {
    return "Bob"
  }
}
```

---

```
// main.js
import Cal from './cal'

console.log((new Cal()).method())
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll give this a try

Comment: Looks like in order to get the import to work, I'll have to use something like WebPack.js to bundle Abe bob and cal up into a single JS file.

Comment: Yes. Here's a simple tutorial http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/

Answer (score 0):

The point is dependencies, we must deal with the correct dependencies(class or function) even in the `c` language.